# PHP message: Notice: Trying to access array offset

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck on next:

I get this error: `Notice: Trying to access array offset on the value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_area\view_rel.php on line 64`. How to solve this error and what kind of error is?

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$get_rel = "select * from bundle_product_relation";
$run_rel = mysqli_query($con,$get_rel);
while($row_rel = mysqli_fetch_array($run_rel)){
$rel_id = $row_rel['rel_id'];
$rel_title = $row_rel['rel_title'];
$bundle_id = $row_rel['bundle_id'];
$product_id = $row_rel['product_id'];
$get_p = "select * from products where product_id='$product_id'";
$run_p = mysqli_query($con,$get_p);
$row_p = mysqli_fetch_array($run_p);
$p_title = $row_p['product_title'];
$get_b = "select * from products where product_id='$bundle_id'";
$run_b = mysqli_query($con,$get_b);
$row_b = mysqli_fetch_array($run_b);
$b_title = $row_b['product_title'];
$i++;
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rel_title; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $p_title; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $b_title; ?></td>
<td><a href="index.php?delete_rel=<?php echo $rel_id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
<td><a href="index.php?edit_rel=<?php echo $rel_id; ?>">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Error is on line 64 and that line of code is `$p_title = $row_p['product_title'];`.

Database is for products:

```
1. product_id
2.p_cat_id
3.cat_id
4.manufacturer_id
5.date
6.product_title
7.product_url
8.product_img1
9.product_img2
10.product_img3
11.product_price
12.product_psp_price
13.product_desc
14.product_features
15.product_video
16.product_keywords
17.product_label
18.status
```

Database for bundle_product_relation:

```
1.rel_id
2.rel_title
3.product_id
4.bundle_id
```

Where im wrong? Thanks all

Comment: ``` $p_title = $row_p['product_title']; ``` This is error @Akintunde-Rotimi

Comment: first use prepared statements https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php  second you should always check for errors see https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Running queries inside a loop is often a bad code design. Use `joins` to avoid this.

Comment: okay, how to resolve this error? @nbk

Comment: I guess you have a `bundles` table. So replace the last query with `select * from bundles ..` not `products`

Comment: show your tables and the desired results please i think also a join would help to make only one query

Comment: I can edit my question with tables from db if that can help. I try what you write not help that create another 3 errors. @FelippeDuarte

Comment: Question is updated @FelippeDuarte

Comment: Do you have a bundle table? Read my comment above.

Comment: No i don't have. @FelippeDuarte

Comment: In code above is writen just `bundle_product_relation` and `products` @FelippeDuarte

Comment: So `bundle_id` is what? A foreign key to what table?

Comment: Foreign key to `products` table. @FelippeDuarte

Comment: I resolve this problem using `isset()` code.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on this question is:

I haved error on line **64** and that line of code is `$p_title = $row_p['product_title'];`.

**Solution for me is:**

From: `$p_title = $row_p['product_title'];` to:

`$p_title = isset($row_p['product_title']);`